# Which IDE to use for C++ game development on windows and on Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, c++, ide, game-development

I am a java developer and I want to learn game programming in C++. I have been using Eclipse, Intellij(recently) for java development.

Please suggest which IDE is best for C++ development.
There are many out there like Visual Studio, CLion, Eclipse, etc.
Which one to use  (Not based on ease of use but the best/rich for long run) ?

Also as I have heard that Linux environment is best to C++ developers, please suggest the best IDE for windows and Linux both.

Here by saying best, I mean :
1. Community/Stackoverflow/google support for issues
2. Rich in controls/shortcuts (Like we know eclipse is great for java on windows but once I started using Intellij I found it much better and faster)
3. Most widely used
4. Rich plugins or modules or libraries support
5. Responsive
etc.

Thanks !

Comment: How about QTCreator?

Comment: This Question as written is not suited to this site. Asking "best for long run" is vague to the point of being meaningless. Please edit your Question to specify criteria by which to judge the possible products meeting your needs. Open-ended discussion questions are not appropriate here.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience on Windows, Visual Studio has been the best to transition to for a Java programmer. It has the largest ecosystem/community of any the editors you mentioned and it would set you up nicely should you choose to pursue any .Net languages, etc.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620919.aspx) is an MSDN link for getting started with c++ in Visual Studio

Comment: For windows and linux both ?    No, I want to learn c++ and not C#.

Comment: @iAmLearning for only the Windows operating system. It works for a variety of languages, including c++

Answer (score 1):

If you like IntelliJ, or other JetBrans products, have you considered [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/)?  Usable on both Windows and Linux (Mac too if you want).  It will have an interface you're familiar with, and you will also be able to use the IntelliJ shortcuts and theme so you won't have to learn a new set of commands.

I don't know just how widely used it is, but there's various plugins for the JetBrains products.  They tend to be quick to work (once indexing has finished on a large project), and I've only ever had one crash from their entire suite across multiple products (and that was an EAP version).

Answer (score 0):

Since you tallking about game development, you should use a game engine like Unreal and this game engine has own IDE.